# WordPress allow HTML in menu description

Tags: wordpress, menu, filter

I looked all over how to allow HTML with links or other tags inside the menu description, but all I can find is how to strip tags with

```
// Allow HTML descriptions in WordPress Menu
remove_filter( 'nav_menu_description', 'strip_tags' );
```

I found this function, that should allow writing links, and other HTML elements in menu description

```
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'cus_wp_setup_nav_menu_item' );
function cus_wp_setup_nav_menu_item( $menu_item ) {
     $menu_item->description = (isset($menu_item->post_content)) ? apply_filters( 'nav_menu_description', $menu_item->post_content ) : '';
     return $menu_item;
}
```

But this will output the page contents in the menu description :\

Any other way around this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your code should look like this:

```
remove_filter( 'nav_menu_description', 'strip_tags' );

function my_plugin_wp_setup_nav_menu_item( $menu_item ) {
    if ( isset( $menu_item->post_type ) ) {
        if ( 'nav_menu_item' == $menu_item->post_type ) {
            $menu_item->description = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_description', $menu_item->post_content );
        }
    }

    return $menu_item;
}

add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'my_plugin_wp_setup_nav_menu_item' );
```

How does your walker class look like? You may not need the `my_plugin_wp_setup_nav_menu_item` filter if you use the value of `$item->post_content` insted of `$item->description`. Also make sure to print the raw value of the menu item description without escaping it with `esc_html` or `esc_attr`.

Comment: This did the trick. I am using `$item->description` to output the description. I'll award the bounty in 14 hours :) Thank you!!

Comment: Hallelujah! Thank you so much!

Comment: Worked like a charm in 5.3! Thank you!

Comment: Great! Happy it's still useful. Thank you!